# Email regular expression with ascii and control characters

Tags: regex, email-validation

I know this is a common question, but I still can't seem to find a great regular expression to use when validating email addresses.
What is the best regular expression you have or have seen for validating emails with below condition?

- email constructor: first_element@second_element
- first_element: the first element (user name part)
- second_element: the second element (domain part)

The condition is: All the element not contain spaces, control characters, or non-ASCII characters.
thanks

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
^[a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$
```

Explanation

[image: Flow]

Comment: Thanks for answering, But is $ a control character?

Comment: `$` is end of string.

Comment: If you think my answer helped, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark. @DinhHoa

Comment: this regex would allow the domain to start with a hyphen which is considered to be illegal.